# how to encode back this string?

Tags: php, encoding, gzip

i have stirng which has been encoded, when i try to decode it with

```
echo gzdecode(base64_decode('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'));
```

everything went well, the problem is when I encode, the result doesn't work

```
echo gzencode(base64_encode('{"identity":{"userId":"84bc7897-81dc-4e23-9d91-8819e0eadd24","authToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiZWRmMzVkN2YtN2M0ZS00OWY4LTk0ZDctOWEwMGNlOTM4NzEwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ5Njk3MTIzLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjowfQ.m3_rpkrF_U8LO8e9NDNzzkaxHSsUzxC0D8eIklPvYi9eo5x5WEdygH8Lk5vk35QO2-mWCugjxypSRCc5KAhoqw","deviceId":"9641305a6d60a72f","appId":"com.hopper.mountainview.play","version":{"value":"5.7.2","buildNumber":116827}},"preferences":{"locale":"id_ID","currency":"USD","timeZone":"Asia/Jakarta"},"savedItems":[{"savedItem":"Carriers","state":{"tag":{"timestamp":"2022-04-09T00:11:03.165+07:00"},"SavedItemState":"MostRecent"}},{"savedItem":"Regions","state":{"tag":{"timestamp":"2022-04-01T23:48:02.318+07:00"},"SavedItemState":"MostRecent"}},{"savedItem":"DefaultLinks","state":{"tag":{"timestamp":"2021-08-20T07:00:00.000+07:00"},"SavedItemState":"MostRecent"}}]}'));
```

and i got the result

> S˒8%^y4%ڠi36n_1s=T%̬,Q-|Ԫ$WKYzi&0
> ~XpL@cqFX q-2q

how to work well, as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what is being done for decode and encode. If you break up each operation into 2 steps you will see what you are doing wrong.

```
base64_decode() takes a string and returns binary data
gzdecode() decodes the binary data into a string
```

When you want to do the reverse, you must reverse the steps and gzencode first.

```
gzencode() the json string into binary data
base64_encode() the binary data into a string
```

So to encode, you would do this:

```
base64_encode(gzencode('{"identity":...}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Your output contained characters that could not be displayed. Make sure you use utf8_encode around your output when working with special characters or binary data.

Try this - It worked for me

```
<?php

    $text = gzdecode(base64_decode('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'));
    
    echo utf8_encode($text);
```